# Using an FFT to identify noise

Tags: noise, fft

First off, please note that I am a hobbyist.

I have a couple of line level audio outputs that are picking up noise from a nearby 12v signal anytime it pulses. These pulses are translating into audible "ticks".

I am able to pick the noise up on my scope (each time the wave form is pulled down, that's a portion of the noise), but I'm having trouble identifying its frequency so that I can add a filter to my outputs to prevent that noise from entering my circuit.

**How can I use the FFT data to point me in the right direction?**

Here's an image of the noise and the FFT:
[image]

Here is a video of the noise as picked up by my scope, with the noise audible:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xg_gBNa48d0

Comment: Instead of filtering the ouputs, can you shield this 12V?

Comment: @Huisman, Unfortunately not. The 12v signal is part of a wire bundle in a large wiring harness for a vehicle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"tick" sounds are usually created by something close to an impulse, or with a significant portion of impulsive energy.  And time domain impulses create broad or wide-spectrum noise in the (FFT) frequency domain.  So you are unlikely to be able to find or remove the majority of this noise with a generic (LTI) filter, such as an EQ or a notch.

If the sound was more like a hum than ticking, then you would have a better chance.

You might instead want to try putting some ferrite beads on the wires from the source of the 12V transient signal.  Or wind those wires through a ferrite toroid.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Unfortunately, I can't modify the wiring as it's part of a large vehicle wiring harness. Would there be merit to placing in-line ferrite beads on my line outputs? I have an amplifier on my PCB that is being back-fed this noise through the line input, which is why I'm trying to quench it.